# Постоянно ввожу set prefix & set root в консоли GRUB2 при входе в Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, boot

Переустановил систему, и поставил Debian. Все с офф сайта. Ставил через флешку. Поставил без проблем.

При первом запуске вылезла консоль GRUB2. Долго мучился, методом тыка зашел в нормальный загрузчик:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
insmod normal
normal
```

После этого защел в систему. Потыкался, обновился, сделал ребут и снова консоль.

Опять много гуглил, обновлял grub, grub2, монтировал, монтировал и без результата. Каждый раз приходиться вводить команды выше, иначе ядро не грузиться.

Переустановка системы не помогает.

Пожалуйста подскажите, что сделать чтобы система загружалась без "танцев с бубном"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вылезла консоль GRUB2

Сама просто так взяла и вылезла? :-) Или было какое-то сообщение об **ошибке**?

Подозреваю, что было сообщение о том, что на диске не найден раздел, содержащий ОС. После это Вы в консоли указываете, где лежит загрузочный образ и груб выполняет загрузку нормально.

Возможно, что во время установки ОС Вы **не** отметили ни один дисковый раздел как загрузочный.  Или у Вас несколько физических HDD и grub не понимает, с какого диска грузить.

Рекомендация:

Возьмите Live-CD (или флэшку), с которого делали установку, загрузитесь в Live режиме, запустите *gpatred* и внимательно посмотрите на таблицы разделов всех подключённых дисков. Скоре всего, проблема где-то там...

Это не ответ, а просто рекомендация.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Вылезает сообщение по типу "*load kernel firs*". А ещё хотел бы заметить, что при выполнении команды *fdisk* ни один раздел не отмечен как *boot*.

Comment: Но проблема в том, что каждый раз приходится прописывать пути в grub, и они не сохраняются. По поводу рекомендации, я посмотрю диски и отпишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Запустил Gparted: [image: Вот что показывает]

При запуске в grub я прописываю:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
```

хотя система смонирована на /sda1. Не могу разобраться... Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

**Решил проблему** покупкой нового ноута. Не смог разобраться, или данная неисправность просто не лечиться.